# Multiple Play/Pause button with audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Im having trouble with more than 1 play/pause button in a same code, i have a table where there is a button and then the song name on cell to the right.

the button works perfectly, here is the code(got it from internet):

```
<script language="javascript">

function play_pause() {

  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");

  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}

</script>
```

And the audio part

```
 <html>
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
     <audio preload="none" id="myAudio" src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"</audio>          
     <img src="play.png"  width=30 height=30 border="0" onclick="play_pause()";>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
     <audio preload="none" id="myAudio" src="music2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"</audio>          
     <img src="play.png"  width=30 height=30 border="0" onclick="play_pause()";>
       </td>
       </tr>    
     </table>
</html>
```

So whenever i play any button on my web, it starts the first song and if i try to play another its like im unpausing the first one (actually only play the first one, even when i sourced another)
Im pretty sure is because of the lack of code in my function, and because both audio tags reference the same ID, but however, what do i exactly have to implement on my script to make my page works fine? I've tried a lot of things but can't really make it works as i want.
I'd highly appreciate some advices, thanks in advance.

Ps: Is not necessary for me now, but if with the code i can also get a change icon for my audio, i mean when "onclick" it i change to a pause icon, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may Put difference between objects like this

```
    function play_pause(player) {

      var myAudio = document.getElementById(player);

      if (myAudio.paused) {
        myAudio.play();
      } else {
        myAudio.pause();
      }
    }
```

And

```
    <html>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
 <audio preload="none" id="myAudio1" src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"</audio>          
 <img src="play.png"  width=30 height=30 border="0" onclick="play_pause('myAudio1')";>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
 <audio preload="none" id="myAudio2" src="music2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"</audio>          
 <img src="play.png"  width=30 height=30 border="0" onclick="play_pause('myAudio2')";>
   </td>
   </tr>    
 </table>
```

EDITS:
Use this loop for more than 4 players

```
   var songs=['song1.mp3','song2.mp3','song3.mp3','song4.mp3'];
   var players="<table>";
   for(var i=0;i<songs.length;i++){
       players+='<tr>
     <td>
 <audio preload="none" id="myAudio_'+i+'" src="'+songs[i]+'" type="audio/mpeg"</audio>          
 <img src="play.png"  width=30 height=30 border="0" onclick="play_pause(\'myAudio_'+i+'\')";>
    </td>
  </tr>';
   }
  players+="</table>"
 document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML=players;
```

and your html

```
 <body> <div id='myTable'></div>    </body>
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for the fast reply! It works now, but i've noticed that if i have more than just 2 audios (which is my case) i don't think i will be able to put as many 1,2,3,4...as the number of songs are, i mean i do have to state a constat right? so will work for as many sons as i have or add later
Any advice is highly apreciate it! Thanks for the reply

Comment: Okay you can add a for loop as I suggested in my last answer. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Im sorry but its not working, or maybe im not putting it right, anyway i have to say that i can't add rows like that since there are many more cells that might result involved by just adding rows like that, i still accept your answer since was very helpful

Comment: hey @Bellash i hope you can help again, i really need it and seems that you know pretty fine your job, i'd really appreciate if you take a look at my other post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343925/toogle-icon-play-pause-and-stop-when-another-button-is-clicked)
Thanks in advance